# WIF - Claims for each entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif, claims

In my application, there is hierarchical data (like tree) and a user can have access on any node of the tree irrespective of the parent. How can WIF help here along with attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty new to WIF, but I would imagine that you shouldn't attempt to store this kind of entity data inside a claim.

If you are not using a reference session then you are asking your user to transmit a potentially huge amount of data to you with each request in a cookie (this include images etc).

You probably only want to include a few claims, perhaps think about the top level of the tree. Anything below that you will want to check with the database (your connection to the database will always be significantly quicker than your users connection to your web app).